# Make cell size small in DT

Tags: r, shiny, dt

I'm trying to make a DT datatable without contant and make the cell really small like 4px. But when I try to use the CSS to make it small it doesn't work.

Here is the code:

```
   tbody tr td {
        border-radius: 50%;
        border: 1px solid black;
        height: 15px;
        width: 15px;
        padding: 15px;
        font-size: 0;
    }
```

After changing it it still looks like 14px big. I just want to reduce it to 5px

[Table output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6jE6M.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different css target, for me I've found this works on datatables:

```
#DataTables_Table_0 {
                       font-size: 5px;

}
```

Depending on how many DataTables are in the shiny it may be `DataTables_Table_1` or `DataTables_Table_2`.

You could also try changing the css while the shiny is live using the developer tools in the browser until you find the right css target.

To give a better answer we'd need to see the code for the entire shiny.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this callback:

```r
library(DT)

js <- "
function(settings) {
  var table = this.api();
  table.rows().nodes().to$().css('font-size', '5px');
}
"

datatable(
  iris,
  options = list(
    "drawCallback" = JS(js)
  )
)
```